# Making a stylesheet(.css) file apply to my MasterPage in Visual Web Developer 2008

Tags: css, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

How can I do this?

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

My CSS file is called default.css and it's located in the App_Themes folder > Default > default.css

Any help? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figure it out.

I dragged the .css file into the code section of the .master page and this popped up:

```
<link href="App_Themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

compared to this that didn't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
```

Now you know. :3 Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your href to: `App_Themes/default/default.css`

Comment: I've edited my question to show what's currently on my .master page, but nothing changes. :(